# Bockstein homomorphism from $H^d(BG,Z_2)$ to $H^{d+1}(BG,Z)$, and Steenrod Square $Sq^1$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

The Theorem 1.5 and 1.6 of

Brown, Edgar H., Jr. The cohomology of BSOn and BOn with integer coefficients. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 85 (1982), no. 2, 283–288.

give a general answer for $H^d(BSO_n,Z)$ and $H^d(BO_n,Z)$, in term of $\delta(w_i)$ and $p_i$, where $w_i$ are the Stiefel-Whitney classes.

Here $\delta$ is the natural map from $H^d(BG,Z_2)$ to $H^{d+1}(BG,Z)$.
So $\delta$ looks like the Bockstein homomorphism (of some sort).

My question is that can we regard $\delta$ as the Steenrod Square $Sq^1$ in the above Theoroms?

Comment: $\operatorname{Sq}^1=\operatorname{Bockstein}$: this is one of the definition (or theorem: there is but one stable operation of degree $1$).

Comment: Doesn't $Sq^1$ map to $H^{d+1}(BG,Z_2)$ rather than $H^{d+1}(BG,Z)$?

Comment: @AD: yes, but it's the Bockstein for the sequence $0\to Z_2\to Z_4\to Z_2\to 0$.

Comment: There is another Bockstein $\beta$ (I think) that maps $H^d(BG,Z_2)$ to $H^{d+1}(BG,Z_2)$. I think $\beta =Sq^1$. But in the theorems, we only care about $\delta$ mod 2. So I wonder, can one say $\delta=\beta=Sq^1$ mod 2.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Well, if your $\delta$ is the Bockstein for $0\rightarrow\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/2\rightarrow0$ then what you can just say is that $\delta$ composed with the change of coefficients along $\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/2$ is $Sq^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural maps from $$0\to Z\to Z\to Z_2\to 0$$ to $$0\to Z_2\to Z_4\to Z_2\to 0$$ commute with the homomorphisms in the s.e.s. and hence also with the connecting homomorphisms of the long exact sequence, i.e. with the Bockstein homomorphisms.

In particular, the Bockstein of the first sequence corresponds to $Sq^1$ after mod 2 reduction.